# Django ModelChoiceField changing widget to checkbox input labels dissapear

Tags: django

I need to change the radio buttons to checkboxes in my application.

```
 event = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Event.objects.all().order_by('-category', 'beginning_date'),
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxInput(),
    )
```

I am creating a choice field with widget but the labels are gone? How can i modify it to show the label?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

in your models and in your forms:

```
class <YourModel>Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = <YourModel>
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = { 'event': forms.CheckboxInput }
```

Comment: I got error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CheckboxChoiceInput'

Comment: Yes ... In django >1.4 CheckboxChoiceInput doesn't exist. I use CheckboxSelectMultiple and it's ok, but maybe you don't want to select more than one value

Comment: In my case i have ManyToManyField in Model declaration and in the model declaration i change widget to CheckboxSelectMultiple

Comment: My case is a little complicated. I have a foreign key field but i need check boxes...